# Who first said this iconic Superman line?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

The famous Superman line is

> It's a bird, it's a plane, no it's Superman!

Who was the first person to say that in a Superman story?

Comment: Well, the famous Superman line would be: "***Save Martha***". But i'm not the one to argue :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1940:** In the form

> Up in the sky! Look! It's a bird! It's a plane! It's Superman!

it was part of the introduction to each episode of the *Superman* [radio serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Superman_(radio_series)), which first aired on February 12, 1940. You can listen to it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/superman_otr/Superman_400212_01_The_Baby_From_Kry.mp3).

Comment: But the question asked for "in the comics", not on radio.

Comment: Think of it this way: You've reduced the number of [issues of Action Comics](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Action-Comics-1938/Issue-1) someone will have to comb through. I lost interest at 4.

Answer (score 12):

In 1941 and 1942, Fleischer Studios produced [a series of seventeen animated shorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_(1940s_animated_film_series)) featuring Superman for Paramount Pictures. (Fleischer produced the first eight as an independent company before being acquired by Paramount in 1942).

> *Look! Up in the sky! It's a bird! It's a plane! It's SUP-er-man!"*

is used as the introductory sequence for the very first one, called "[The Mad Scientist](https://youtu.be/4zTK7hI-T64)". The "speakers" are random people in the street.  The titles contain a caption

> COPYRIGHT MCMXLI *Paramount Pictures, Inc.*

Comment: A Yahoo Answer [on this question](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081130211432AAtJzEa) links to http://saratogaconcepts.com/superman.html but the link is dead

Comment: @Stormblessed That website appears to be devoid of content except one embedded version of the Superman video I linked to elsewhere. Archive.org only crawled it twice;the first is just an empty stub and the second is the single link-free page in the live version you can go to.

Comment: Thank you for that, was this line only used this one time then has it become one of those things that everyone thinks was said or written more then it was?

Comment: Well, *technically* it's "SOUP-er-man". Supperman is an entirely different character. :-)

Comment: But the question asked for "in the comics", not in film.

Comment: @RayButterworth So, it's your contention that an animated cartoon is a "film" and not a "comic"?

Comment: @Spencer I would argue that it is an animated cartoon, not a comic. A comic would normally mean a set of sequential non-animated cartoon images drawn on paper or a static digital equivalent.

Comment: Have amended the question and selected the other answer as that is an earlier version then this but still interesting to read about